# Android onWindowFocusChanged called to early

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, oncreate, activity-lifecycle

In my activity needs to download an image from a webservice, therefore I wrote an `updateUi` method which get called in `onCreate()` to hide the ui elements (because of missing data at this time) and to show a simple `TextView` with a message like "data loading...".

Then I use the `onWindowFocusChanged` with a loaded `boolean` to call it only one time. In the `onWindowFocusChanged` I download all data I need from the webservice and call `updateUi` again to show the original ui and hide the "data loading" `TextView`.

The goal is to immediately open the new activity after the user pressed a button instead of hidden processing while the user don't know what's happening.

I have like 10 other activities where this method works very well without any trouble, but in this particular activity it seems like `onWindowFocusChanged` get called before the new activity shows up. If I click on the button to open the activity nothing happens on the display for some secs and then the activity starts with the original ui with all data filled in.

I don't understand why the activity doesn't show up with the "data loading.." `TextView` instead of doing the tasks in `onWindowFocusChanged` while the activity didn't show up already?

The code is the same like in my other activities, does someone have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed, that the problem doesnt exists in the first creation of the activity. if i click on a button which start the activity the first time the textview with the loading message is showing and the other ui elements are hidden.

if i leave the activity an start it again the problem occurs...